# Vectors get rasterized when exported to ePub

Tags: adobe-indesign, epub

I have an InDesign file with some vectors (some of them are direct paths, and some are just linked from Illustrator). But every time I export to ePub they look super pixelated (unless I set export settings to maximum which makes my file huge).

Any idea why ePub is not exporting scalable vectors, and seems to just rasterize them into .png's instead?

Comment: Why down-voting or closing this question?? Imho, it is a very relevant one... :-/

Answer (score 3):

I am not an Epub specialist, but afaik Epub does support only one kind of vector file, which is SVG.

Problem is: Indesign does not (yet) have the native abilily of importing SVG files. (You can vote for this request here: https://indesign.uservoice.com/forums/601021-adobe-indesign-feature-requests/suggestions/31159285-svg-import)

Looks like some paid plugins can do the job, but haven't tested them.
Check this out: https://indesignsecrets.com/svg-import-and-export-means-better-epubs.php